# Safe line reading in Rust

Tags: rust

I can't understand how to read line in Rust safe.
I know the only way to read string:

```
std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut mystring);
```

But according to documentation, this method doesn't have limit so that a program will crush if string overloads buffer.

Is there any way to read string safe.

Comment: What do you mean by "if string overloads buffer"? Strings resize dynamically as much as needed, so you would likely need a single line measured in billions of bytes to run out of memory on any modern system.

Comment: The word "safe" has a very specific meaning in the context of Rust. Running out of memory is considered "safe".

Comment: @justinas I know, but if it happens, a program will crash. That is why I am interested.

Comment: @SvenMarnach really? what happens then? Can I use ```stdin().read_line(&mut mystring).expect("read error")``` to prevent it?

Comment: I find it hard to imagine a situation where limiting the size of a string read from `stdin` would prevent an OOM error. If you're reading from an untrusted TCP connection, okay, maybe you need to limit the size. But in what threat model does an attacker have *unbuffered* access to your program's standard input stream?

Comment: Crash is, unfortunately, an overloaded word. Could you please specify _in your question_ if you want to avoid (1) an uncontrolled crash -- result of memory corruption, dangling pointer dereference, etc... or (2) a controlled, but unwanted, stop -- result of stack overflow, out of memory, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [take()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.take) on any `io::Reader`, which will limit the maximum number of bytes read from the underlying source before returning `EOF` unconditionally:

```
use std::io::{self, Read, BufRead};
io::BufReader::new(io::stdin().take(1024)).read_line(&mut mystring);
```

If you want to actually detect this situation, you can create a "[limited reader](https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io/blob/cf8962345b0fcc2d4002ef8e80ee081635917ea2/src/util/io_util.rs#L5)" as a thin wrapper around `stdin`, which will return an error in case more than `x` bytes are read.

Comment: Yes, limited reader is what I need, I think. But I am a complete beginner in Rust. Could you please give an example of usage of it?

Comment: Commented example at https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b2c9bc4b989cf400cf74a0142c0aebc2

Comment: The problem with this solution is if you want to use `stdin` afterwards. Every time you create one a full buffer is read, and when it is dropped the unused bytes in that buffer are discarded. So the next read will have skipped a number of bytes.

Comment: @rodrigo: I would note that any use of `BufReader` presents the same issue, since the `BufReader` internally buffers -- which means moves data from `stdin` to its internal buffer -- so that creating a `BufReader` on `stdin`, reading a bit, then dropping it will generally consume extra bytes from `stdin`.

Comment: Which is why [`Stdin::lock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lock) exists. I wonder what happens with `stdin().lock().take(n).read_line(&mut mystring)`, if `n` is not a UTF-8 character boundary.

Comment: @trentcl: Wonder no more, I just tested and it returns an error as expected: `Err(Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: "stream did not contain valid UTF-8" })`.

Comment: @user2722968: I should consider changing your answer to the similar code of @trentcl in the comment above. It works because the return of `stdin().take()` already [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Take.html#impl-BufRead) `BufRead`.

Answer (score 2):

A `BufReader` implements the `BufRead` interface which provides both a low and high level interface.

The high-level interface includes `read_until` and `read_line` and will read until a specific byte is encountered in the input -- this may indeed result in an Out of Memory exit.

The low-level interface is comprised of 2 important methods:

- `fill_buf`, which reads bytes into the internal buffer, then returns a reference to it.
- `consume`, which drops bytes from the internal buffer.

They can be used in combination to read with fixed-sized buffers:

```
let mut reader = std::io::BufReader::new(std::io::stdin());

loop {
    let buffer = reader.fill_buf()?;
    let consumed = {
        // do stuff with some bytes.
    };
    reader.consume(consumed);
}
```

Care must be taken to *always* consume in the above loop. A single `continue` could ruin your day, as then `fill_buff()` would return the same buffer ad nauseam.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is dynamically resized in Rust, so you can just do:

```rust
let mut mystring = String::new();
std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut mystring).unwrap();
```